# How to use Array in spring boot mybatis annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I received an array of columns from Frontend. I need SELECT ---- WHERE [Received Array] = 1. However, the length of the array is dynamic.

That is, a query with a value of 1 should be written for each column received in the array.

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE product_type = #{product_type} AND product_location = #{product_location} AND $(myArray) = 1")
    List<product> getOptionedProduct(@Param("product_type") String product_type, @Param("product_location") String product_location, @Param("myArray") List<String> myArray);
```

myArray has [A, B, C]
I want to write like

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE product_type = #{product_type} AND product_location = #{product_location} AND A = 1 AND B = 1 AND C = 1")
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<foreach />` tag ([doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach)).

To use tags in annotation, you need to enclose the entire statement with `<script />` tag.

```java
@Select({
  "<script>",
  "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE product_type = #{product_type} ",
  "AND product_location = #{product_location} ",
  "<if test='myArray != null'>",
  "  <foreach item='columnName' collection='myArray' separator=' and ' open=' and '>",
  "    ${columnName} = 1",
  "  </foreach>",
  "</if>",
  "</script>"
})
List<product> getOptionedProduct(
  @Param("product_type") String product_type, 
  @Param("product_location") String product_location, 
  @Param("myArray") List<String> myArray);
```

If you use Java 15 or later, you can benefit from text blocks ([JEP-378](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378)).

```java
@Select("""
  <script>
  SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE product_type = #{product_type}
  AND product_location = #{product_location}
  <if test="myArray != null">
    <foreach item="columnName" collection="myArray" separator=" and " open=" and ">
      ${columnName} = 1
    </foreach>
  </if>
  </script>
  """)
```

As `myArray` is a list of column names (right?), you have to use `${}` instead of `#{}`.
So, you need to make sure that `myArray` does not contain any unexpected string to avoid SQL injection, etc..
See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the details.

Comment: Good answer, However, the OP should not consider using an array with a massive number of values. The database engine may have some limits in terms of the length of the resulting SQL statement.

Comment: As the example `A`, `B`, `C` is not descriptive enough, I am not so sure, but the requirement implies a bad design. A separate table with two columns (`reservation_id` and `flag`), for example, might be more appropriate.